# Confusion over c# class with an image

Tags: c#, image, class

I am creating a project that will read in a datafile using a `streamreader` and display the data in a windows form.

However one of the properties of that datafile is an image. Since I have never actually used images before, in c#, I am slightly confused.

Doing some prior research I have created a class called `team` and managed to set up the declaration of the `Image` `using System.Drawing;` but I am not sure how I am supposed to set up the constructor for the class with an image or the getting/setting methods.

All I have managed to find online is general uses and tips for the `Image` class nothing on putting it in your own created class. Here is what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace teams_2
{
class Team
{
    string teamName;
    string teamLeague;
    string teamManager;
    string teamNickname;
    string teamStadium;
    int leaguePosistion;
    int leaguePoints;
    int gamesPlayed;
    int goalDifference;
    int playerNumber;
    Image teamLogo; //the problem

    //constructor(image?)
    //team order = teamName teamLeague teamManager teamNickname teamStadium leaguePosistions leaguePoints gamesPlayed goalDifference playerNumber teamLogo

    public Team( string inTeamName, string inTeamLeague, string inTeamManager, string inTeamNickname,
                 string inTeamStadium, int inLeaguePosistion, int inLeaguePoints, int inGamesPlayed,
                 int inGoalDifference, int inPlayerNumber)
    {//
        teamName = inTeamName;
        teamLeague = inTeamLeague;
        teamManager = inTeamManager;
        teamNickname = inTeamNickname;
        teamStadium = inTeamStadium;
        leaguePosistion = inLeaguePosistion;
        leaguePoints = inLeaguePoints;
        gamesPlayed = inGamesPlayed;
        goalDifference = inGoalDifference;
        playerNumber = inPlayerNumber;

    }//end constructor
    //begin getters
    public string getTeamName()
    {
        return teamName;
    }
    public string getTeamLeague()
    {
        return teamLeague;
    }
    public string getTeamManager()
    {
        return teamManager;
    }
    public string getTeamNickname()
    {
        return teamNickname;
    }
    public string getTeamStadium()
    {
        return teamStadium;
    }
    public int getLeaguePosistion()
    {
        return leaguePosistion;
    }
    public int getLeaguePoints()
    {
        return leaguePoints;
    }
    public int getGamesPlayed()
    {
        return gamesPlayed;
    }
    public int getGoalDifference()
    {
        return goalDifference;
    }
    public int getPlayerNumber()
    {
        return playerNumber;
    }
    //end getters

    //begin setters
    public void setTeamName(string inTeamName)
    {
        teamName = inTeamName;
    }
    public void setTeamLeague(string inTeamLeague)
    {
        teamLeague = inTeamLeague;
    }
    public void setTeamManager(string inTeamManager)
    {
        teamManager = inTeamManager;
    }
    public void setTeamNickname(string inTeamNickname)
    {
        teamNickname = inTeamNickname;
    }
    public void setTeamStadium(string inTeamStadium)
    {
        teamStadium = inTeamStadium;
    }
    public void setLeaguePosistion(int inLeaguePosistion)
    {
        leaguePosistion = inLeaguePosistion;
    }
    public void setLeaguePoints(int inLeagePoints)
    {
        leaguePoints = inLeagePoints;
    }
    public void setGamesPlayed(int inGamesPlayed)
    {
        gamesPlayed = inGamesPlayed;
    }
    public void setGoalDifference(int inGoalDifference)
    {
        goalDifference = inGoalDifference;
    }
    public void setPLayerNumber(int inPlayerNumber)
    {
        playerNumber = inPlayerNumber;
    }
    //end setters

}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your getters/setters are a bit odd.. You would normally use properties like so: `public string PropName { get { return _field; } set { _field = value; } }`. In reference to your question, there's no reason you can't include the `Image` obj in your constructor like you do with the other fields.

Comment: Hi! C# has something called properties (and automatic properties). This is something you should google (Not related to your question at all, but related to the code you posted)

Comment: You're coming from Java, aren't you? I call tell by the naming convention. I think it's better to use properties instead of getter and setter methods.

Comment: what are you confused about with the constructor? What do you actually want the constructor to do? People are right the getter and setters are odd but there is nothing technically wrong with this. Only thing I can see is that youre not exposing your image anywhere so it is only available in the class? Do you want to stream into the image? Do you want to populate it in the constructor or not? How do you intend to read the image....many many question?

Comment: The image gets it path from the datafile being read in (this is being done by someone else) so I can't really clarify anymore on that unfortunately. I would like the image displayed on a windows from in vs2010 so I am assuming I want it exposed there.

Comment: Also what's confusing me about the constructor is the fact I simply don't know what to put inside the parenthesis for an image. It's the same for the getter/setter methods. How do I create one for an image? is it the same as the int/string methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off using the bitmap class rather than the image class as it allows you to reference the image from a file path

So Here is my solution

```
Image logo = new Bitmap("Path");

    public Image getlogo()
    {
        return logo;

    }
```

There should be no need for a setter as it is set when it is declared

Edit i have tried this solution and it still worked even with a png so give it a try

Hope this helps Enjoy

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the logo given to us in the project must be .png so I don't think I can use this. My fault for not clarifying this earlier.

Comment: @zac: Pls read the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx  Bitmap class can read PNG

Comment: Sorry the way you phrased it made me think differently haha. Thank you the answer works perfectly.